# List space used by indexes

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We are using NoSQL database Marklogic 8. My team recently created a lot of indexes on Marklogic to improve performances. We now have several and we need to clean them. In order to perform this clean, we want to know which indexes are the bigger in term of Memory.

Is-it possible to list all indexes with the used memory per index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the size of the index in memory should be proportional to the number of items in the index, and you can use [`cts:count-aggregate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:count-aggregate) to get the number of items. Some datatypes use more memory, so you should take that into consideration if you are comparing indexes of different types.